# Why does my project reference point to a dll in the "obj" directory?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, project-reference

I'm adding a project reference to a project, that already has a few project references added to it. If I inspect the existing ones' properties, they all have paths to their projects' `bin` directory, e.g.:

`C:\MyProject2\bin\Debug\MyProject2.dll`

However, when adding another project reference, it ends up with a path pointing to its `obj` directory:

`C:\MyProject3\obj\Debug\MyProject3.dll`

That dll doesn't even seem to exist! (Although that might be because I can't get the entire solution to compile yet.)

Why would one project reference point to the bin, and another to obj? And how to correct it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When the referenced project isn't built, the reference's path will point to a DLL in the obj directory. After it has been built, the path will automatically point to a (now existing DLL) in the bin directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can correct it easily by editing the project in notepad and changing the path. Alternatively right click the project in the solution choose unload, then edit. Then once changed right click in project and choose reload.

Comment: The path to the dll is not in the project file. The project file only contains the path of the `csproj` file of the referenced project. E.g.: `<ProjectReference Include="..\..\MyProject3.csproj">`

Comment: Have you tried clearing out all the generated directories (obj,bin) and then re-adding project reference having removed it. This looks a VS problem I can't reproduce it. My project references are bin.

Comment: I have now tried cleaning the solution then adding the project reference, but it had the same result.

Comment: I am guessing MyProject3 has been built and is building to the normal bin folder nothing weird like that.

Comment: You found the problem! The referenced project had not been built yet!

Answer (score 1):

I fix this issue by editting the `Build Dependecies` -> `Project Dependencies` to make sure the dependecies is the same as the project reference. In my case, some of the referenced project is not selected in the `Project Dependencies`.

Comment: This was the situation in my case as well. After unloading and reloading the project, the path was changed to bin.